# C++ Is it possible for a DLL and an executable to communicate from a different process?

Tags: c++

Is it possible for a DLL and an executable to communicate from a different process?

For an example:

```
Child.dll is loaded into Target.exe...
Owner.exe is running...
Owner.exe sent message "close" to Child.dll
Child.dll received message "close" from Owner.exe
Child.dll executed: ExitProcess( 0 );
Target.exe has exited, therefore Child.dll has already been unloaded.
```

So, is it possible? If so, how? Thanks.

Comment: Look for IPC http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365574(v=vs.85).aspx, I guess from "Owner.exe sent message "close" to Child.dll" you mean "Owner.exe sent message "close" to Target.exe", if so IPC should work for you...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A DLL does not run in a separate process, it runs in the process space of the process which invokes some methods or accesses data contained within the DLL.

So if no processes are present using a DLL, the operating system may decide to swap the pages of memory mapped for the DLL to the SWAP space or even unload the DLL entirely from the memory.

Comment: I meant to say that the DLL is operating within a different process.

Comment: Yes it is possible to implement various interprocess communication techniques in a DLL to communicate between two or more processes. Shared memory, Sockets, Semaphores are some such primitives. Try searching on these topics.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible through "[inter process communication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication)". Note that with IPC, you don't send a message to the DLL, you send it to the other process. So if process A wants to tell process B a message, it does so (using whatever means they've established for communication, like sockets, shared memory, named pipes, etc.). It's possible for the IPC code to live in a DLL.

Note that you can't talk to a DLL by itself, like you've outlined in your question. You have to talk to the process (but again, the code that handles the communication for the process may live in a different DLL).

One reason for this is that multiple processes can be using the same DLL at the same time. If you've got two processes running, both of them using `Child.dll`, and you want to send a message to `Child.dll` a message, which process should get that message? It doesn't quite make sense, seeing as the two processes are entirely independent of each other, even if they're both using the same DLL. Hence, you can't talk to a DLL by itself; rather, you talk to a process.